# Retrieve data from 3 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Query

```
SELECT     
    dbo.SI_Customer.cst_Name, dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_DocNo,    
    dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_Date, dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.invcm_TotalAmount, 
    dbo.SI_ReceiptMaster.recm_DocNo, dbo.SI_ReceiptMaster.recm_Date,    
    dbo.SI_ReceiptMaster.recm_TotalAmount
FROM         
    dbo.SI_Customer 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SI_ReceiptMaster ON dbo.SI_Customer.cst_Code = dbo.SI_ReceiptMaster.cst_Code 
FULL OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster ON dbo.SI_Customer.cst_Code = dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster.cst_Code
WHERE     
    (dbo.SI_Customer.cst_Code = '001813')
```

Below is the result from this query - I don't want to repeat these values

[image]

Comment: You don't want to repeat, so what do you want to do ?

Comment: What do you mean by *don't want to repeat* ..... those are the rows your query returns - what do you want to do with those?? What **do you** want to see as a result set?? SQL Server is a **database server** - it will return **all the data** for the rows you request - it won't *suppress* repeating values - that's something that should be done in the front end, e.g. a reporting tool or something.

Comment: use GROUP BY on the columns you dont want to repeat

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Will remove truly repeated data, however most of what you have shown is unique data, you need to tell us the rules for what you want to hide etc

Comment: Let me tell you whole story I have to get All the Invoices & receipt Amount ,Date, And Document Number (DocNo) for the Customer (i have three tables customer , invoiceMaster, ReceiptMaster) cst_code Filed have in all three Tables...........

Answer (score 0):

As these rows contain different data, i.e the date and the numbers either side of the date, each row is unique and therfore will show all the colums selected.

You could remove some of the columns and do a group by and SUM or failing this you could produce a report in BIDS and Group by Date and have the other data you dont want repeating as CHILD groups.

Comment: Group by Not Working For this 67    28 Aug 2009  68400 This is Single Entry in Invoice table but Repeats Due to Recept Data Show All After Again it take 2nd Invoice data and show REcept data again i dont want this i simply want to remove this repetation of Invoice data

Answer (score 0):

"Fools rush in" - try:

```
SELECT     
    c.cst_Name, 
    m.invcm_DocNo,    
    m.invcm_Date, 
    m.invcm_TotalAmount, 
    m.recm_DocNo, 
    m.recm_Date,    
    m.recm_TotalAmount
FROM dbo.SI_Customer c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cst_Code,
                  invcm_DocNo,
                  invcm_Date, 
                  invcm_TotalAmount, 
                  CONVERT(varchar(10), null) recm_DocNo, 
                  CONVERT(datetime, null) recm_Date,    
                  CONVERT(decimal(25,8), null) recm_TotalAmount
           from dbo.SI_InvoiceMaster
           where cst_Code = '001813'
           union all
           SELECT cst_Code,
                  CONVERT(varchar(10), null) invcm_DocNo,
                  CONVERT(datetime, null) invcm_Date, 
                  CONVERT(decimal(25,8), null) invcm_TotalAmount, 
                  recm_DocNo, 
                  recm_Date,    
                  recm_TotalAmount
           from dbo.SI_ReceiptMaster
           where cst_Code = '001813') m
       ON c.cst_Code = m.cst_Code
WHERE c.cst_Code = '001813'
```

Comment: Got this Error after Applying your code 

Both Tables(InvoiceMaster & receiptMaster) have Different  Colums and Data Types

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Comment: which line does it highlight when you double click the error message

Comment: @BravealiKhatri: This is probably because I have defined the _DocNo, _Date and _TotalAmount values as strings for the complementary tables, then UNIONed them with non-string data. They need to be converted to the correct datatypes, but I don't know what those are - can you include the DDL (ie. the `create table` statements) for `SI_ReceiptMaster` and `SI_InvoiceMaster` in your question?

Comment: Let me tell you whole story I have to get All the Invoices & receipt Amount ,Date, And Document Number (DocNo) for the Customer (i have three tables customer , invoiceMaster, ReceiptMaster) cst_code Filed have in all three Tables..

Comment: @BravealiKhatri: As I said in my previous comment, I **need** to know the **datatypes** of the _DocNo, _Date and _TotalAmount fields. Your last comment did not tell me anything new.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SI_InvoiceMaster](
 [docs_DocCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
 [doctyp_Code] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
 [invcm_DocNo] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [invcm_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [cst_Code] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
 [invcm_TotalAmount] [decimal](25, 8) NOT NULL,


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SI_ReceiptMaster](
 [docs_DocCode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
 [doctyp_Code] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
 [recm_DocNo] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [recm_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL, 
 [cst_Code] [varchar](6) NOT NULL, 
 [recm_TotalAmount] [decimal](25, 8) NOT NULL,

Comment: @BravealiKhatri: Thanks - I have updated my answer accordingly. I think it should work now - can you include any errors if it doesn't?

Comment: SAme Error Msg

Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: @BravealiKhatri: I noticed that I was selecting the wrong columns from the invoice and receipt tables - I have now corrected this. Can you try the amended code?

Comment: I Already check that and Correct Accordingly but nothing change... same error

Comment: @BravealiKhatri: I have tried running the query in the answer against the table definitions you included and I don't get any error.